# jQuery "return false" works in version 1.6 but not 1.6.1 (rails 3)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

The following code used to function without attempting to render a new template with jQuery verion 1.6. I installed jQuery 1.6.1 and now a radio button click results in an attempt to render a new page.

FYI, the form was submitted on each click because quite a few clients would complete part of the questions, close the browser and expect their work to be there when they came back to finish. If there is a better way, I'd love to know it.

in the application.js on development machine:

```
$('.submittable').live
    ('change', function() 
        {
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
        return false;
        }
    );
```

Again, this works in jQuery 1.6 but not 1.6.1. I used [this tutorial](http://trevorturk.com/2010/08/24/easy-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/) as a guide.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: continuation of this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201964/rails-3-jquery-ajax-can-i-change-this-to-submit-one-answer-instead-of-the-e).

Comment: `*blah*.submit()` will cause the form to POST/GET. What are you expecting? Only when the JS bound to the Submit event of the form returns `false` will the form not be submitted...

Comment: Hello, @GregB. i have "return false;" above. Is my syntax wrong? Can you show me how it should look? Any "mumblings" would be greatly appreciated :=]

Comment: jay, how can you submit the form but want to cancel it with `return false`. Can you describe what you're wanting to do

Comment: You're returning `false` from the handler of your radio's `change` event, not from your form's `submit` event. Seems like you want to submit the form via Ajax, maybe, to prevent a full page reload? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @GregB, thanks for your interest. What it used to do, but changed after installing jquery (rails 3): on click of the radio button response (with a number range from 1 to 5) the data would be sent to the controller without rendering the same or a different page.

Comment: @Jay: the code as you posted is returning false from the change event.  If the javascript code worked prior to jQuery, then I'd be amazed, since it's jQuery library functions...  Without seeing what the code was before you converted to jQuery, it's hard to say why the jQuery version doesn't work.

Comment: @thedaian, well... it worked for about two months :=]... appreciate your perspective. i'll check the code that is on our production host and confirm that it is the same tho.

Comment: @thedaian, see the update above.

Comment: @Jay: strange.  And you're *sure* you don't have jQuery on your production machine?  Perhaps you have another framework on production? Or an older version of jQuery?  If the javascript code didn't change, then it's likely that the problem exists elsewhere.  (Maybe there's an issue with Rails and jQuery that I just don't understand...)

Comment: @thedaian... ok... really embarrassed now :=]. jQuery is on the production machine... faulty memory. But everything is working as it should there.

Comment: Based on your comment to sadmicrowave, the "proper solution" is definitely to do what ajm said, and submit the form via AJAX, since the expected behaviour for a form submit is to refresh the page. EDIT: As per your new comment, yeah, it probably is something else happening.  No idea what changed, but good luck!

Comment: @thedaian, please post this as an answer and i'll switch the correct answer over to you. It was a different version of jQuery. i changed to 1.6 min on the development machine vs 1.6.1 full version on the production machine. Changing back eliminated the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @thedaian, @GregB, @CaptSaltyJack and @sadmicrowave, thanks for your help. I'd love to have you take a shot of the continuation of this issue in the post referenced above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was one version of jQuery on the production machine and another on the development machine. We changed from 1.6 full to 1.6.1 min on the development machine. When i changed it back the problem disappeared. Thanks for all your help guys. Kudos to thedaian. I'll switch the answer over to him if he posts.

Comment: I'm just glad to help.  The most I did was point you in different direction, since the javascript didn't seem to have changed.  Good to know the problem is solved.

Comment: v1.6 is not recommended, it has the potential to break many jQuery plug-ins and any existing code you have. There's a whole deal about $.attr() vs $.prop() that was resolved in v1.6.1 (basically backwards compatibility was added, as it should've been in v1.6).

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack, I've updated the post with what has turned out to be the real problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for trying, but it still tries to render a new template.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your linear chain of events... You are submitting the form every time and then trying to return false...perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function(){
   if( /some condition/ ){
       $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    } else {
       return false;
    }
 });
```

Comment: you are right. the form was submitted each time without rendering the page. We did this because quite a few clients would complete part of the questions, close the browser and expect their work to be there when they came back to finish.